"const defaultCommand = “dev”; " not found in "node_modules/.bin/next" In Plesk
I deployed my Next.js project on Plesk following the steps in this link.
https://medium.com/@keithchasen/how-to-set-up-your-next-js-app-on-plesk-server-7d8d247a2db2
There's a step where I need to edit
node_modules/.bin/next 
and change
const defaultCommand = “dev” 
to
const defaultCommand = “start” 
However, when I checked the next file, it doesn't show const defaultCommand = “dev” but instead appears differently.
Below is code show in node_modules/.bin/next
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
require("../server/require-hook");
const _commander = require("next/dist/compiled/commander");
const _log = require("../build/output/log");
const _semver = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default(require("next/dist/compiled/semver"));
const _picocolors = require("../lib/picocolors");
const _formatclihelpoutput = require("../lib/format-cli-help-output");
const _constants = require("../lib/constants");
const _utils = require("../server/lib/utils");
function _interop_require_default(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
        default: obj
    };
}
if (_semver.default.lt(process.versions.node, "18.17.0")) {
    console.error(`You are using Node.js ${process.versions.node}. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v${"18.17.0"} is required.`);
    process.exit(1);
}
// Start performance profiling after Node.js version is checked
performance.mark("next-start");
for (const dependency of [
    "react",
    "react-dom"
]){
    try {
        // When 'npm link' is used it checks the clone location. Not the project.
        require.resolve(dependency);
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(`The module '${dependency}' was not found. Next.js requires that you include it in 'dependencies' of your 'package.json'. To add it, run 'npm install ${dependency}'`);
    }
}
class MyRootCommand extends _commander.Command {
    createCommand(name) {
        const cmd = new _commander.Command(name);
        cmd.addOption(new _commander.Option("--inspect").hideHelp());
        cmd.hook("preAction", (thisCommand)=>{
            const cmdName = thisCommand.name();
            const defaultEnv = cmdName === "dev" ? "development" : "production";
            const standardEnv = [
                "production",
                "development",
                "test"
            ];
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
                const isNotStandard = !standardEnv.includes(process.env.NODE_ENV);
                const shouldWarnCommands = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? [
                    "start",
                    "build"
                ] : process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [
                    "dev"
                ] : [];
                if (isNotStandard || shouldWarnCommands.includes(cmdName)) {
                    (0, _log.warn)(_constants.NON_STANDARD_NODE_ENV);
                }
            }
            process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || defaultEnv;
            process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME = "nodejs";
            if (thisCommand.getOptionValue("inspect") === true) {
                console.error(`\`--inspect\` flag is deprecated. Use env variable NODE_OPTIONS instead: NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next ${cmdName}`);
                process.exit(1);
            }
        });
        return cmd;
    }
}
const program = new MyRootCommand();
program.name("next").description("The Next.js CLI allows you to develop, build, start your application, and more.").configureHelp({
    formatHelp: (cmd, helper)=>(0, _formatclihelpoutput.formatCliHelpOutput)(cmd, helper),
    subcommandTerm: (cmd)=>`${cmd.name()} ${cmd.usage()}`
}).helpCommand(false).helpOption("-h, --help", "Displays this message.").version(`Next.js v${"14.2.1"}`, "-v, --version", "Outputs the Next.js version.");
program.command("build").description("Creates an optimized production build of your application. The output displays information about each route.").argument("[directory]", `A directory on which to build the application. ${(0, _picocolors.italic)("If no directory is provided, the current directory will be used.")}`).option("-d, --debug", "Enables a more verbose build output.").option("--no-lint", "Disables linting.").option("--no-mangling", "Disables mangling.").option("--profile", "Enables production profiling for React.").option("--experimental-app-only", "Builds only App Router routes.").addOption(new _commander.Option("--experimental-turbo").hideHelp()).addOption(new _commander.Option("--experimental-build-mode [mode]", "Uses an experimental build mode.").choices([
    "compile",
    "generate"
]).default("default")).option("--experimental-debug-memory-usage", "Enables memory profiling features to debug memory consumption.").action((directory, options)=>// ensure process exits after build completes so open handles/connections
    // don't cause process to hang
    import("../cli/next-build.js").then((mod)=>mod.nextBuild(options, directory).then(()=>process.exit(0)))).usage("[directory] [options]");
program.command("dev", {
    isDefault: true
}).description("Starts Next.js in development mode with hot-code reloading, error reporting, and more.").argument("[directory]", `A directory on which to build the application. ${(0, _picocolors.italic)("If no directory is provided, the current directory will be used.")}`).option("--turbo", "Starts development mode using Turbopack (beta).").addOption(new _commander.Option("-p, --port <port>", "Specify a port number on which to start the application.").argParser(_utils.myParseInt).default(3000).env("PORT")).option("-H, --hostname <hostname>", "Specify a hostname on which to start the application (default: 0.0.0.0).").option("--experimental-https", "Starts the server with HTTPS and generates a self-signed certificate.").option("--experimental-https-key, <path>", "Path to a HTTPS key file.").option("--experimental-https-cert, <path>", "Path to a HTTPS certificate file.").option("--experimental-https-ca, <path>", "Path to a HTTPS certificate authority file.").option("--experimental-upload-trace, <traceUrl>", "Reports a subset of the debugging trace to a remote HTTP URL. Includes sensitive data.").action((directory, options, { _optionValueSources })=>{
    const portSource = _optionValueSources.port;
    import("../cli/next-dev.js").then((mod)=>mod.nextDev(options, portSource, directory));
}).usage("[directory] [options]");
program.command("export", {
    hidden: true
}).action(()=>import("../cli/next-export.js").then((mod)=>mod.nextExport())).helpOption(false);
program.command("info").description("Prints relevant details about the current system which can be used to report Next.js bugs.").addHelpText("after", `\nLearn more: ${(0, _picocolors.cyan)("https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#info")}`).option("--verbose", "Collects additional information for debugging.").action((options)=>import("../cli/next-info.js").then((mod)=>mod.nextInfo(options)));
program.command("lint").description("Runs ESLint for all files in the `/src`, `/app`, `/pages`, `/components`, and `/lib` directories. It also provides a guided setup to install any required dependencies if ESLint is not already configured in your application.").argument("[directory]", `A base directory on which to lint the application. ${(0, _picocolors.italic)("If no directory is provided, the current directory will be used.")}`).option("-d, --dir, <dirs...>", "Include directory, or directories, to run ESLint.").option("--file, <files...>", "Include file, or files, to run ESLint.").addOption(new _commander.Option("--ext, [exts...]", "Specify JavaScript file extensions.").default([
    ".js",
    ".mjs",
    ".cjs",
    ".jsx",
    ".ts",
    ".mts",
    ".cts",
    ".tsx"
])).option("-c, --config, <config>", "Uses this configuration file, overriding all other configuration options.").option("--resolve-plugins-relative-to, <rprt>", "Specify a directory where plugins should be resolved from.").option("--strict", "Creates a `.eslintrc.json` file using the Next.js strict configuration.").option("--rulesdir, <rulesdir...>", "Uses additional rules from this directory(s).").option("--fix", "Automatically fix linting issues.").option("--fix-type <fixType>", "Specify the types of fixes to apply (e.g., problem, suggestion, layout).").option("--ignore-path <path>", "Specify a file to ignore.").option("--no-ignore", "Disables the `--ignore-path` option.").option("--quiet", "Reports errors only.").addOption(new _commander.Option("--max-warnings [maxWarnings]", "Specify the number of warnings before triggering a non-zero exit code.").argParser(_utils.myParseInt).default(-1)).option("-o, --output-file, <outputFile>", "Specify a file to write report to.").option("-f, --format, <format>", "Uses a specific output format.").option("--no-inline-config", "Prevents comments from changing config or rules.").option("--report-unused-disable-directives", "Adds reported errors for unused eslint-disable directives.").option("--no-cache", "Disables caching.").option("--cache-location, <cacheLocation>", "Specify a location for cache.").addOption(new _commander.Option("--cache-strategy, [cacheStrategy]", "Specify a strategy to use for detecting changed files in the cache.").default("metadata")).option("--error-on-unmatched-pattern", "Reports errors when any file patterns are unmatched.").action((directory, options)=>import("../cli/next-lint.js").then((mod)=>mod.nextLint(options, directory))).usage("[directory] [options]");
program.command("start").description("Starts Next.js in production mode. The application should be compiled with `next build` first.").argument("[directory]", `A directory on which to start the application. ${(0, _picocolors.italic)("If no directory is provided, the current directory will be used.")}`).addOption(new _commander.Option("-p, --port <port>", "Specify a port number on which to start the application.").argParser(_utils.myParseInt).default(3000).env("PORT")).option("-H, --hostname <hostname>", "Specify a hostname on which to start the application (default: 0.0.0.0).").addOption(new _commander.Option("--keepAliveTimeout <keepAliveTimeout>", "Specify the maximum amount of milliseconds to wait before closing inactive connections.").argParser(_utils.myParseInt)).action((directory, options)=>import("../cli/next-start.js").then((mod)=>mod.nextStart(options, directory))).usage("[directory] [options]");
program.command("telemetry").description(`Allows you to enable or disable Next.js' ${(0, _picocolors.bold)("completely anonymous")} telemetry collection.`).addArgument(new _commander.Argument("[arg]").choices([
    "disable",
    "enable",
    "status"
])).addHelpText("after", `\nLearn more: ${(0, _picocolors.cyan)("https://nextjs.org/telemetry")}`).addOption(new _commander.Option("--enable", `Enables Next.js' telemetry collection.`).conflicts("disable")).option("--disable", `Disables Next.js' telemetry collection.`).action((arg, options)=>import("../cli/next-telemetry.js").then((mod)=>mod.nextTelemetry(options, arg))).usage("[options]");
program.parse(process.argv);

//# sourceMappingURL=next.map


I'm unsure how to proceed. Note that I don't have SSH access granted by Plesk.
I need my project to be operational. Previously, I followed steps to change dev to start as per the link provided, but this time, I couldn't make the change from dev to start at all.

First
Edit line 81-83
program.command("dev", {
    isDefault: true
}).description("Starts Next.js in development mode with hot-code reloading, error reporting, and more.").argument("[directory]", `A 

isDefault to false
Second
program.command("start", {
    isDefault: true
}).description("Starts Next.js in production mode. The application should be compiled with `next build` 

add
{
    isDefault: true
} 

